# Creating Crisp or sharp graphics with R for importing into PowerPoint

Tags: r, svg, plot

This is probably a duplicate, although I cannot find a similar post with `Google` or via the `Questions that may already have your answer` feature on `Stack Overflow`.

I am unsure of the best way to create crisp or sharp graphics with `R` that can then be imported into, for example, `PowerPoint`.

Below is code that creates a `PDF` file.  The resulting image is extremely fuzzy and of very poor quality when imported into `PowerPoint`.

Next I show code and instructions for creating nice crisp images using the `Cairo` package.  However, this involves importing the resulting file into a third-party software called `Inkscape` and saving the file to a new format before importing the file into `PowerPoint`.

Is there a way to create nice sharp graphics that does not involve an intermediate step of importing files into a third-party software?

Thank you for any suggestions.  Sorry if this is a duplicate.  Here is the code:

```
setwd('c:/users/markm/simple R programs/')

a <- seq(1,20)
b <- a^0.25
plot(a, b, bty = "l")

pdf("example_pdf_plot_Oct5_2015.pdf")
     plot(a, b, bty = "l")
     title('Example PDF Plot')
dev.off()

#
# After creating the file below with the Cairo package:
#
# 1. Install the free software 'Inkscape'
# 2. Open the *.svg file with Inkscape and save as a *.emf file.
# 2b. Click 'OK' when asked to convert texts to paths.
# 2c. Click 'Close without saving'
# 3. Import the *.emf file into PowerPoint as a picture.
# 4. Resize and position image in PowerPoint to taste.
#
# install.packages('Cairo')
library(Cairo)

CairoSVG('example_svg_plot_Oct5_2015.svg', onefile = TRUE, pointsize = 12, width=8, height=6, bg="white")
     plot(a, b, bty = "l")
     title('Example SVG Plot')
dev.off()
```

Comment: If you build your R script in R Markdown, you can set `fig.retina=2` in the knitr options and it'll do all of the point size (etc) machinations for you. if you name the code chunks well you get good filenames too.

Comment: @hrbrmstr I am not familiar with `R Markdown`.  Is that a GUI like `R Studio`?  Perhaps it is part of `R Studio`?

Comment: https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/rmarkdown/index.html

Comment: @hrbmstr: is that fig.retina=2 a command also in LaTeX?  I am trying to improve the quality of .png files using a .Rnw script.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at package `ReporteRs`

```
library(ReporteRs)

my_graph_fun <- function( ){
  a <- seq(1,20)
  b <- a^0.25
  plot(a, b, bty = "l")  
}

doc = pptx()
doc = addSlide(doc, "Title and Content")
doc = addPlot(doc, fun = my_graph_fun )
writeDoc(doc, "example.pptx")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is `R` code that creates a file that seems equally crisp as an `SVG` file created with `Inkscape`.  No intermediate editing of the `TIFF` file is needed.  Just import the `TIFF` file created by `R` directly into `PowerPoint`.

```
tiff(file = "example_tiff_plot_Oct5_2015.tiff", 
     compression= "lzw", width = 8, height = 6, res = 500, unit = "in", pointsize = 12)

     plot(a, b, bty = "l")
     title('Example Tiff Plot')

dev.off()
```

Here is another approach that someone suggested to me.  The resulting file from this `png` approach is smaller in size than a `TIFF` file and I guess may rescale better.

```
a <- seq(1,20)
b <- a^0.25

png(file = "example_png_plot_Oct6_2015.png", 
     width = 8, height = 6, res = 500, unit = "in", pointsize = 12)

     plot(a, b, bty = "l")
     title('Example Png Plot')

dev.off()
```